# Vector Notation in optimization problems

Tags: amsmath, vector

I am typing optimization problems in latex. Half of the variables are vectors. First I used bold to mention vectors, but it looked ugly. Now I am using `$\mathbbmss{p}$` but I am not sure if this looks neat

```
\begin{aligned}
{\mathop{\arg\max}\limits_{\vec{\theta}}}\; && \mathbbmss{p}_k(\theta)\mathbbmss{q}-p_B\mathbbmss{q}_B&\\
&\text{s.t.}&&\mathbbmss{p}_k,\mathbbmss{q},\;\mathbbmss{q}_B\in\mathbb{R^N},\;p_B\in\mathbb{R}
\end{aligned}
```

Comment: could you turn your snippet into a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)  :)

Comment: What's your actual question though?

Comment: Is there a commonly accepted notation for such formulations? In som e papers I saw that authors use bold, some use \vec{}, I know simple answer is do whatever you want, but I appreciate comments f more experience math people.

Comment: This is highly subjective but I usually 1) use `\vec` (so it's easier to change the appearance of vectors should it be necessary) and 2) load [`isomath`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/isomath/isomath.pdf) and `\let\vec\vectorsym`, because it usually works out (and arrows are ugly).

Answer (score 1):

I read this question as a beg for an evaluation of the "neatiness" of the fonts of the package `bbm` when used for vectors. So it seems to be a style question and style questions are

- objective / neutral, if style are standardized. Then you shouldn't post this question here but to whoever set up this standard of using `bbm`s fonts.
- subjectiv / personal, if not:

No, I don't find them neat at all. They differ so much from the normal math characters, that they distract a lot. They also seem artificial and kind of ugly. If you can, use a unicode-enabled engine such `xetex` or `luatex`, a `unicode-math`-enabled font such as Asana Math, TG Pagella Math or XITS Math, and the math alphabets provided by these fonts. Then, all the characters are of one style.